# SQL Server web service requests on Fiddler

Tags: sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2008, fiddler, msxml

In SQL Server I call web service but can't see on the fiddler. How can I trace requests from sql server on fiddler?

**PS:** I tried setProxy but nothing changed.

This is my code:

```
--DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[WS_IsEInvoiceUser]
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[WS_IsEInvoiceUser]
    @vkn varchar(20),
    @username VARCHAR(50)='FreseniusMedikal',
    @password VARCHAR(50)='xxxx',
    @ResponseText as Varchar(8000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Request INT
    Declare @Body as varchar(8000) = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <s:Header>
            <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                <o:UsernameToken>
                    <o:Username>'+@username+'</o:Username>
                    <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">'+@password+'</o:Password>
                </o:UsernameToken>
            </o:Security>
        </s:Header>
        <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <IsEInvoiceUser xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                <vknTckn>'+@vkn+'</vknTckn>
                <alias/>
            </IsEInvoiceUser>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>'  
    EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Request OUT;
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Request, 'setProxy', NULL, '2', 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Request, 'open', NULL, 'post','https://efatura.uyumsoft.com.tr/Services/Integration', 'false'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Request, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'SOAPAction', 'http://tempuri.org/IIntegration/IsEInvoiceUser'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Request, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Request, 'send', null, @body

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Request, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
    SELECT CHARINDEX('true', SUBSTRING(@ResponseText, CHARINDEX('IsSucceded="true" Value="', @ResponseText)+LEN('IsSucceded="true" Value="'), 5))


    Exec sp_OADestroy @Request
END
```

Comment: Fiddler works within your current login session, but SQL Server is running as a service in a different session. There are ways to run Fiddler as system (would need the same thing to intercept requests from within IIS).

Answer (score 1):

First, you definitely do have to call `setProxy` or else your `ServerXMLHTTPRequest` won't route the traffic through Fiddler, so you're on the right track there. Having said that, I'm not sure your parameters are right, per [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/804037/Using-MSXML-from-a-SP-on-SQL) they should be:

```
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Request, 'setProxy', '2', 'http://127.0.0.1:8888', ''
```

... which matches the [declaration on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760236(v=vs.85).aspx).

For a HTTPS request to succeed, you will need to ensure that Fiddler's root certificate is trusted in the MACHINE's trusted root store. In Fiddler, choose Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS and click "Export root certificate to desktop." Then run MMC.exe and add the "Certificates" snapin. Choose "Computer account". Drag/drop the FiddlerRoot.cer from your desktop to the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" folder in the mmc console and accept the prompts.